# Two-way OOP design-pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

This is kind of a general question, let me formulate it in a particular scenario. I am coding a pricing system. In one hand there are several "engines", on the other, several "instruments". I created class hierarchies for both of them.

My problem comes now that I want to implement a pricing mechanism. Given a specific engine AND an a specific instrument, together they determine the algorithm to calculate a price. It would be nice to code it in 2-entries table. Both instances contain vital information, none seems more important than the other. In OOP methods belong to one class, so I see no decent design to deal with this: the "pricing" method should be in the Instruments class, or the Engines?

Whatever way I go I have the same problem. Suppose I decide it should be in the engines. Then, inside the pricing methods I should have an 'if-then-else' instruction dealing with each possible InstrumentClass? This seems way too ugly (and tight coupling!), specially if I am going to have to check it with something like

```
isinstance(inst, InstrClass1)
```

I can imagine similar situations arise in many contexts. What is the best design-pattern to deal with them?

**REPHRASED as a Vehicle + Circuit example**

Say you have, on one hand, a class hierarchy of Vehicles. There are Motorbikes, Cars, etc. a particular object
may be a Yahama Ray, it is an instance of Motorbike, also a Vehicle.

On the other hand, you have Circuits. And classes LeMans, Jerez, LagunaSeca, etc.

What we want to do is to simulate the performance of a given vehicle in a given circuit. For instance, suppose
the output is the time it takes the vehicle to complete one lap. For Motorbikes and Cars the physics are different,
so you have different algorithms. But also suppose in some Circuits you need to take into account some factors
that in other are irrelevant. So, only when you know all the details of the vehicle and the circuit, can you simulate.
You cannot ask the circuit to "simulate itself" and get a time, then ask also the vehicle to "simulate itself" and give
you another time, and finally cook the final answer with those two.

Hopefully this sheds some light on what I am trying to do.

Comment: If it's about combinations it should be in something that represents the combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal answer to this question as the solution will always be domain-specific.

However, as a general guideline, if there is logic that doesn't fit in any existing object then you are simply missing an additional concept and this concept is usually represented as a stateless service, but not always.

For instance, let's say that there is a discount of `15%` when `Engine1` and `Instrument1` are bought together.

Obviously, the discount logic doesn't belong to either of `Engine1` or `Instrument1`, but you could probably have an `Order` that contains both items and the order could have a way to apply discounts. The `Discount`s could inspect an `Order` to know if their application policy is satisfied and could return back a discount amount for a specific order.

```
class Order {
    ...

    public void applyApplicableDiscounts(List<Discount> discounts) {
        for (Discount discount : discounts) {
            if (discount.isApplicableTo(this)) {
                this.discounts.add(discount);
            }
        }
    }

    public Price netPrice() {
        return sumAllOrderLinePrices();
    }

    public Price totalPrice() {
        Money discountAmount = sumAllDiscountAmounts();

        return netPrice().deduct(discountAmount);
    }
}

class Engine1BoughtWithInstrument1Discount implements Discount {
    public boolean isApplicableTo(Order order) {
        return order.containProducts(/*Engine1, Instrument1*/);
    }

    public Money amountFor(Order order) {
        return order.netPrice().percentageOf(15);
    }
}
```

Now, for the vehicule + circuit example it's the same thing. You would probably have a stateful `Simulation` or a stateless `SimulationService` that can run a simulation given a vehicule, circuit, wheter, physic laws, etc. This could get very complex, but essentially these various collaborators should allow the component performing the simulation to query them in order to gather the details it needs to perform the simulation.

Unfortunately, I do not know anything about this domain and physic laws, but as a very simple example (probably silly), the simulation service could query the circuit to know the terrain at a specific point in it and ask the vehicule for it's wheel's surface and shape to know how much friction would be generated.

Comment: plalx@ Thanks, I'll think about it, this gives me a starting point!

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to have a CalculatorService that has a method that takes in an engine and an instrument. It can contain the logic that will consolidate the engine price and instrument price. Individual prices will come from the Engine and instrument objects, so encapsulation will not be broken.

```
class CalculatorService {
   public BigDecimal calculatePrice(Instrument instrument, Engine engine) {
    def instrumentPrice = instrument.calculatePrice()
    def enginePrice = engine.calculatePrice() 
    //algorithm to consolidate both prices.
   return consolidatedPrice
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it does not suit my example. My mistake, maybe I should have given more specifics. Let me change the example a bit, to a more familiar setup: Vehicles and Circuits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a 3rd type: Pricing, which uses an instance of Instrument and an instance of Engine.  The Pricing class is responsible for calculating the price.